# Better git workflow with two shared active branches

Tags: git, version-control, github

We have git workflow close to one explained here [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Let's ignore release and hotfix branches, cause they don't relate to this issue. I have now three branches:

- master
- develop
- feature

Now I am in team X and we start working on a feature branch called `feature/A`. Meanwhile, team Y is working on other feature branch `feature/B`. Team Y also finishes `feature/C`, and `feature/D`

Here, I am in a strange position. I need to keep up with `develop` branch because team Y has merged there. I also need to keep up with 'feature/A' branch cause other team members are making changes.

My preferred way of keeping up with the changes - `rebase` cause lots of trouble as I need to constantly rebase in two different branches.

`merge` is somehow working, but I still think there must be better way.

How do you work with such setups? I did try searching on how people work with it, but can't find any lead.

The above workflow in the link also doesn't explicitly say anything about such setups.

Hosting is on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, as soon as you start a feature branch, you are isolated from the other development lines. So when working on feature A, you should by default never pull in changes from `develop` or other branches (especially not from other feature branches). If your development requires some changes from `develop` to be integrated before you can continue (for example when there was something added you depend on), then you can merge once from `develop` into your branch. But in general, you would try to avoid that to keep the development separated. Then, when you are done, you merge your feature branch into `develop` and the feature branch can go.

Rebasing is never a good idea when working in a team. Once you published something, you should *never* rebase it again. Doing so will create new commit objects with new hashes, so your branches will point to different objects breaking the history for everyone else. You can rebase locally before you pushed it, for example to clean up your own commits. But beyond that, better don’t do it.

Other than that, you can just use `git fetch` to fetch all changes from the remote repository. Fetching will update your remote branches, i.e. `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, `origin/feature/A` etc. So whenever you want to refer to the current state of the remote repository, you can use the remote branches. Your local branches though (`master`, `develop`) will not automatically update. And unless you are working with them, you don’t necessarily need them to be updated anyway. And if you do, just check them out, and fast-forward merge with their remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to keep up with `develop` - only with `feature/A`. The leader of team X(which might be you with a different hat) should make sure that `feature/A` is up-to-date with `develop`. That way each branch is rebased againts a single branch.

Comment: Yes, I am the one with different hat. That's why I am here.

Edit: I think I got your point. only one person for keeping up with develop, rest will only care about `feature/A`.